# if $y=5+\int_{2}^{2x}e^{-t^2}\,dt$, why does $y(1)=5$

Tags: calculus

This is an AP Calculus AB question and the choices included:
$$D. \frac{dy}{dx}=2e^{-4x^2}, y(0)=5$$
$$E. \frac{dy}{dx}=2e^{-4x^2}, y(1)=5$$
the answer says that $E$ is the correct answer but I couldn't figure out to put $1$ into the equation

Comment: Look at the limits when $x=1$, in this case, the integral starts and ends at $2$, so the value when $x=1$ is zero.  For the rest, use the $u$-substitution, $2u=t$, then the limits change to $1$ and $x$ and you can use FTC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

$$
\int_2^2 e^{-t^2}dt \;\; = \;\; 0.
$$

In fact for any function $f(t)$ you have that the integral is zero when evaluated at the same limit:

$$
\int_a^a f(t)dt \;\; =\;\; 0.
$$

Remember that in Riemann integration this is like asking the question "what is the area under $f(t)$ at the point $a$?"  This region can't have area since it has no width.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is an integrable function $\int_a^a f(x)\,dx = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For any integrable function $f$,

$$\int_a^a f(x)\,dx=0$$

The intuition behind this is clear. The integral is the signed area of the graph of $y=f(x)$ between the limits, i.e. between the lines $x=a$ and $x=a$. But that is one vertical line, and the area "between the line and itself" is just zero.

In your case, looking at $y(1)$, the limits in your integral are $2$ and $2$, so the integral is clearly just zero, and your total expression for $y(1)$ is $5$.